# Show processlist use question marks instead of binded values

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, prepared-statement

Then I run "show full processlist" in MySQL I see that some queries looks like

`| 413575 | sitecom | localhost | sitecom | Prepare | 0 | After opening tables | select * from content where content.id = ? | 0.000 |`

`| 413597 | sitecom | localhost | sitecom | Prepare | 0 | init | select * from content where content.id = ? | 0.000 |`

Site is using Laravel Eloquent ORM. It works through PDO with prepared statements. Is that Ok that I see question marks instead of binded params?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but if someone stumbles across this: It's normal that the processlist in MySQL shows question marks. The queries are with the binded values, you just don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, but after activating slow_query_log, processlist shown all parameters again